# Splitting a string withisalnum and store into a vector of strings

Tags: c++, string, parsing, stringstream

I'm working with a string and trying to break it up whenever it is non-alphanumeric (not a-z, A-Z, and 0-9). I found isalnum to be a useful function to use.

For example, if I have the string "bob-michael !#mi%@pa hi3llary-tru1mp"

The vector should contain: bob, michael, mi, pa, hi3llary, and tru1mp.

My current code is:

```
  vector<string> result;
  string something = "bob-michael !#mi%@pa hi3llary-tru1mp";
  stringstream pie(something);
  //not sure what to do after this point(I know, not a lot. See below for my current thinking)
```

My idea was using a loop and while isalnum results in 1 continue forward, if isalnum results in 0 then push whatever I have so far into the vector of strings. Perhaps I could use isalnum as a delim? I'm having a hard time taking my idea and writing this. Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Edit: Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Quick hack: [Use `std::replace_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) on the string to transform all of the non-alpha characters into spaces and then put the modified string into the `stringstream`.

Comment: MMM, I expected that, (well `replace_if(something.begin(), something.end(), &isalnum, " ");`) to work, but looks like `isalnum` needs to be wrapped because it returns `int`. Will formally answer in a moment.

Comment: The way I did it was I created a boolean function that returns "return isalnum(i) == 0;" and put that function call into the third parameter. I think it works I will test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`std::replace_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) trick I commented on turned out to not be quite as trivial as I thought it was because [`std::isalnum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalnum) doesn't return `bool`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    std::string something = "bob-michael !#mi%@pa hi3llary-tru1mp";
    // I expected replace_if(something.begin(), something.end(), &isalnum, " ");
    // would work, but then I did a bit of reading and found is alnum returned int,
    // not bool. resolving this by wrapping isalnum in a lambda
    std::replace_if(something.begin(),
                    something.end(),
                    [](char val)->bool {
                          return std::isalnum(val) == 0;
                     },
                     ' ');
    std::stringstream pie(something);

    // read stream into vector
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(pie),
              std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
              std::back_inserter<std::vector<std::string>>(result));

    // prove it works
    for(const std::string & str: result)
    {
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick question, when reading the stream into a vector is there a way to ensure there are no duplicates. For example if there are two strings "pie" and "pie", I would only like to read it in once

Comment: @MMM in a `vector`, no. Not without searching it and not adding the duplicate. If you don't care about preserving the insertion order, a `std::set` discards duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
std::vector<std::string> result;
std::string something = "bob-michael !#mi%@pa hi3llary-tru1mp";
std::regex token("[A-Za-z0-9]+");

std::copy(
    std::sregex_token_iterator(something.begin(), something.end(), token),
    std::sregex_token_iterator(),
    std::back_inserter(result));
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/ROJS65430)

Comment: Oh, woops. My bad. Apologies

Comment: Btw, pretty slick, Igor =)

Answer (score 1):

You can also iterate through the string and then check if the current index is a letter or not, then if not break it then store to vector

```
std::string something = "bob-michael !#mi%@pa hi3llary-tru1mp";

std::vector<std::string> result;

std::string newResult = "";

for ( int a = 0; a < something.size(); a++ )
{
      if((something[a] >= 'a' && something[a] <= 'z')||(something[a] >= 'A' && something[a] <= 'Z')
          || (something[a] >= '0' && something[a] <= '9'))
      {
          newResult += something[a];
      }
      else
      {
         if(newResult.size() > 0)
         {
            result.push_back(newResult);
            newResult = "";
         }
      }
}
result.push_back(newResult);
```